# Lotus Script computed field handling

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus

I am facing an issue in handling computed fields from lotus script agent. Please find below description:

There are two fields in Main form (web main form) Start Date and End Date,text fields,which are computed fields and are being computed using DBcolumn, and then on submit button, agent is called.

In lotus script agent I want to use values of these two fields, but I am unable to use them using document context but can not get the value of these fields.

Eg. EndDate=doc2.EndTime  ( doc 2 is session.document context)

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `EndDate=doc2.EndTime(0)` as the field content is returned as an array (also for single value fields)

Comment: @Peter Thanks for this, but already tried that, not working. Got the answer, I had to call the agent on WebQuerySave instead of button click.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer, I had to call the agent on WebQuerySave instead of button click.